# ¿Cómo filtrar datos en una tabla en SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla y me gustaría hacerle un filtrado, la idea es que me me muestre solo los campos que cumplan con lo siguiente: si tienen desde el año 2023 Periodo 04 al Año 2024 Periodo 03, es decir que tengan 13 periodos, que me arroje los valores. En caso de que no tengan los 13 periodos completos que no me muestre ni un campo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que cuando meta el código me arroje lo siguiente ya que es el único depto-clase-familia que tiene los 13 periodos, estoy intentando con el siguiente código, pero no me muestra lo que quiero:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Tabla1
WHERE NumPeriodo BETWEEN 1 AND 13
ORDER BY NumDepto, NumClase, NumFamilia, NumAnio, NumPeriodo
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y pusiste 3 bases de datos distintas porque?????

Comment: Todo esta en la misma base de datos

Comment: que es cual?? sql server? mysql? postgres??? son todas bases de datos distintas...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes intentarlo con particiones de SQL (partitions) y expresiones comunes de tabla (cte)

El siguiente query te regresa el número total de periodos agrupando numAnio, numDepto, numClase, numFamilia

```
SELECT numAnio, numPeriodo, numDepto, numClase, numFamilia,
count(*) over (partition by numAnio, numDepto, numClase, numFamilia) numTotalPeriodos
FROM Tabla1
```

Ya solo sería filtrar los que tengan 13 periodos en total, yo lo hago con cte's, aunque se podría hacer con consultas anidadas

```
WITH cte1 as(
SELECT numAnio, numPeriodo, numDepto, numClase, numFamilia,
count(*) over (partition by numAnio, numDepto, numClase, numFamilia) numTotalPeriodos
FROM Tabla1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte1
where numTotalPeriodos = 13
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Realmente me funcionó!!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes agrupar por numero de familia y clase, después sumar los periodos para saber cuáles tienen los 13, la suma de los 13 son 91.

```
SELECT SUM(NumPeriodo) as SumaPeriodos,
NumDepto,NumClase,NumFamilia
Group by NumFamilia,NumClase,NumDepto
Having SUM(NumPeriodo) = 91
```